# Loading local text file to simpleMDE

Tags: javascript, html, flask, simplemde

Lately I have started using simpleMDE in my website, and I ran into a problem loading a local text file to my markdown editor, using a input button.
I was also unable to delete the previous data and change it to "".
I built my website using flask, and I am using flask simpleMDE to load simpleMDE to my website.
my code:

hello.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flask-SimpleMDE example</title>
    {{ simplemde.css }}
    {{ simplemde.js }}
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="file">
    <textarea>
    Some Markdown Text Here
    </textarea>
</div>
<script>

let input = document.querySelector('input')

let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')

// This event listener has been implemented to identify a
// Change in the input section of the html code
// It will be triggered when a file is chosen.
input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    let files = input.files;

    if (files.length == 0) return;

    /* If any further modifications have to be made on the
       Extracted text. The text can be accessed using the
       file variable. But since this is const, it is a read
       only variable, hence immutable. To make any changes,
       changing const to var, here and In the reader.onload
       function would be advisible */
    const file = files[0];

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.result;

        // This is a regular expression to identify carriage
        // Returns and line breaks
        const lines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        textarea.value = lines.join('\n');

    };

    reader.onerror = (e) => alert(e.target.error.name);

    reader.readAsText(file);
});

  var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({
    autofocus: true,
    autosave: {
        enabled: true,
        uniqueId: "MyUniqueID",
        delay: 1000,
    },
    });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

my app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
from flask_simplemde import SimpleMDE

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SIMPLEMDE_JS_IIFE'] = True
app.config['SIMPLEMDE_USE_CDN'] = True
SimpleMDE(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I try running the file without the flask, I obviously can't see the `simplemde` but seeing the textarea and able to load a text file into it using the input button, and when running the flask app I am able to see the simpleMDE but unable to load a text file into it.
any suggestings?